# How to construct date_select values into single date format using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a date_select in my html form. I know that it separates the day month and year. I am trying to work out how to construct a date in the form YYYY-MM-DD within my Javascript, in order to send this date to my controller to be compared against other dates.

Here is what I've got so far (I am a JQuery/JS beginner):

```
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

    var year = $("#event_day_1i").val();
    var month = $("#event_day_2i").val();
    var day = $("#event_day_3i").val();
    var selectedDate = [year + "-" + month + "-" + day];

...
$.ajax({
            url: '/events/check',
            data: {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate },
            method: "POST"
        }
    );
)};
```

But this creates dates such as "2016-2-4" instead of "2016-02-04". What is the best way of fixing this problem?

If you have a solution that allows me to send the 3 separate values to be constructed into a date within my controller then that is also great, but I don't know how I would do that either (beginner).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea is the same with @Phillip answer. The only difference is integer count and character length counting.

Use **parseInt()** to convert it to integer.

Use **length** to count the characters or string.

This checks if the value is **single character**, then appends "0" to it, e.g. 1 will become "01".

```
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

    var year = $("#event_day_1i").val();
    var month = $("#event_day_2i").val();
    var day = $("#event_day_3i").val();

    if (day.length < 2) { day = '0' + day; }
    if (month.length < 2) { month = '0' + month; }

    var selectedDate = [year + "-" + month + "-" + day];

...
    $.ajax({
            url: '/events/check',
            data: {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate },
            method: "POST"
        }
    );
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd ensure the user added a number in each field. You can do more extensive checking yourself, but I'd gotten you started with a `.parseInt()` JS method.

After you have an integer store in that variable, check if it's less than 10. That is, would only be one digit.  You may also want to check if it's greater than 0 as well.

Once you know that, concatonate the string of "0" in front of it.  ie: `9` becomes `09`.

```
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

var year = $("#event_day_1i").val();
var month = $("#event_day_2i").val();
var day = $("#event_day_3i").val();
month = month.parseInt();
day = day.parseInt();

if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
}
if (day < 10) {
    day = "0" + day;
}
var selectedDate = [year + "-" + month + "-" + day];
```

...

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/events/check',
            data: {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate },
            method: "POST"
        }
    );
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

another way of prepending the "0" is to use the following (only a portion of the code listed):

```
day = ("0" + day).slice(-2);

month = ("0" + month).slice(-2);
```

what this does is add the "0" to the start and then takes the last two characters. Note that both this and the other way return these values back to strings.